# How to resolve NoSuchFieldError: TOO_MANY_REQUESTS exception in Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] after moving from JDK8 to JDK17?

Tags: java-17, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TOO_MANY_REQUESTS] with root cause

Dependencies versions used are:
1.0.2.4
1.0.2

**Complete error log**:

```
URLBasedX509CertificateSupplier  : suppressX509Workaround flag set to false
2023-06-01 15:06:49.072 INFO 10 --- [http-nio-9070-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TOO_MANY_REQUESTS] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TOO_MANY_REQUESTS
        at com.oracle.bmc.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfiguration.<clinit>(CircuitBreakerConfiguration.java:37)
        at com.oracle.bmc.util.CircuitBreakerUtils.<clinit>(CircuitBreakerUtils.java:32)
        at com.oracle.bmc.auth.AbstractFederationClientAuthenticationDetailsProviderBuilder.createFederationClient(AbstractFederationClientAuthenticationDetailsProviderBuilder.java:207)
        at com.oracle.bmc.auth.AbstractFederationClientAuthenticationDetailsProviderBuilder.build(AbstractFederationClientAuthenticationDetailsProviderBuilder.java:192)
```

I have tried changing the versions of the above libraries and using the latest SDK but it is failing post moving from JDK8 to JDK17

Comment: Wild guess, but you migrated your application from JAX-RS to Jakarta namespace. The class CircuitBreakerConfiguration uses the field TOO_MANY_REQUESTS from the javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status class, and if you've migrated to jakarta, this field does not exist anymore, thus causing the failure you've described.

Comment: https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/7f9184b198adf882e8c6d61730d45eb7a637daaa/bmc-circuitbreaker/src/main/java/com/oracle/bmc/circuitbreaker/CircuitBreakerConfiguration.java#L37